# Forcing all images to be rendered before adsense ads load

Tags: google-adsense, images, responsive-webdesign, google-adsense-policies, resolution

I have a problem. On my mobile pages where each page consist of a large picture, I have it set with CSS so that the image fits the entire available width of the screen. I want to avoid using fixed image sizes for small screens as that lowers the responsiveness aspect of the page.

The problem is that I'm making $0 RPM from adsense for that page and I think it is because the image auto-resizes itself one split second after the advertisement loads thereby pushing the ad unit down which I believe violates adsense law.

I can't move the adsense ad above the image or the display wouldn't look proper because when people use the mobile site, the only thing that interests them are the pictures.

Is there a way I can force all images to load completely at the formatted size (with CSS rules applied) before the adsense ad begins to load? or is this something that can't be controlled?